# Why didn't Gordon take these characters to safe location?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In the last episode *Melinda* of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*,

> There was a female Inhuman having super strength who stole Terrigen crystals for her daughter. She and her daughter both were causing chaos. Plus, they were both attracting unnecessary attention to get killed (If Melinda wasn't there, military would do that anyway).

Why didn't Gordon take them away and lock them out like Skye's father?

Comment: Gordon makes a big deal about how Cal isn't one of them; I got the sense that they had rules about how they treat their own

Answer (score 3):

Because SHIELD got to them first.  We see Gordon and Jiayang arrive after SHIELD was on the scene, and with SHIELD around, Gordon and Jiayang were unable to intervene, as doing so would reveal themselves.  So they let things play out, and fortunately, May was able to end the crisis.

Comment: Seriously? He took Raina, Cal and Skye all in front of S.H.I.E.L.D.

Comment: Other than that Gordon seems to know about everything happening in the world.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 I don't think we know enough about the Inhumans in the MCU to give a better answer yet.

Comment: I got the impression they were there to monitor the mess they were causing, not to help. The mother had already fled their sanctuary; we don't know if they'd give her a second chance.

Comment: Jiayang is not exactly impartial when it comes to the Cal and Daisy situation. Additionally, she has some seven years of perspective after the Bahrain incident to change how they react to threats to their group.